# Loop over Array and get the distinct ids

Tags: php, functions, array

I've made a loop that goes over all the gigs I've attended, some gigs have the same songs.

Here is the result of that array: 
http://snippi.com/s/k80v7pe

Now I want to have an array of all the distinct song id's. So want to see all the songs that I've ever heard:

```
//get the songs field get_field('songs')
foreach ($postIds as $postId){ 
    array_push($songIds, get_field('songs', $postId));  
} 

//Over here I'm trying to print all the ID's of the song
foreach ($songIds as $songId) {
    echo $songId->ID;
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in

Is that because of that the array `$songIds` has an array in an array?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's because you are treating an [array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) as an [object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) and `PHP` doesn't convert those types automatically. To get an individual element from an object you use:

```
$my_object->Element1;
```

To get an individual element from an array you use:

```
$my_array[Element1];
```

You can even nest arrays. So if you have $my_array, where each element is another array, you can get elementX from arrayY like this:

```
$my_array[arrayY][elementX];
```

In your case, apparently, you have an array, which holds an array, which holds objects, amounting to:

```
$my_array[arrayY][elementX]->componentZ
```

Comment: I have this: foreach ($songIds as $songId) {
  echo $songId[0]->ID;
  echo "<br />";
 }
But it only gives the ID's of the first gig.

Comment: You''ll have to loop through $songid[i]

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to do that exactly. Do I have to do a foreach in a foreach? Some like this? foreach ($songIds as $songId) {
  foreach ($songId as $item) {
  echo $item[0]->ID;
  echo "<br />";
  }
  
 } But replace the [0] with a counter?

Comment: foreach ($songIds as $songId) {
  foreach ($songId as $key => $value) {
   print_r($key[$value]);
   echo "<br />";
  }
 }

Comment: foreach ($songIds as $songId) {for ($i = 0; $i < count($songid); $i++) { echo $songId[$i]->ID; echo "<br />"; } }

Answer (score 0):

Because `$songIds` is an array within an array, I have to do 2 loops within each other.

The code below pushes all post id's from the different arrays in a new array `$allSongs`.

This way I have an array with all the id's. Some id's will be duplicates because some songs are played more than 1 time over all the gigs.

```
foreach ($songIds as $songId) {
    foreach ($songId as $key => $value) {
        array_push($allSongs, $value->ID);
    }
}

//all songs
print_r($allSongs);
```

To retrieve only unique id's, you can use the array function `array_unique` to remove the duplicates from an array.

```
$uniqueSongs = array_unique($allSongs, SORT_REGULAR);
print_r($uniqueSongs);
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Simply posting code doesn't make for a complete answer. Try to include some explanation with your answers.

Comment: Thank you!
I will edit my post immediately.